# How can I remove the socket.io polling logs from my NodeJS app on heroku?

Tags: node.js, sockets, logging, heroku

Heroku doesn't support websockets, so in using socket.io, my logs have become super cluttered by `/socket.io/` lines. How can I make them go away?

```
2015-05-26T20:57:50.842359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/someUsername/today/update" host=complice.co request_id=48483d1f-5389-4dc9-a7e2-0dd975e4cdaf fwd="132.205.236.27" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=57ms status=200 bytes=366
2015-05-26T20:57:50.846807+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.24.23 - - [26/May/    2015:20:57:50 +0000] "POST /someUsername/today/update HTTP/1.1" 200 17
2015-05-26T20:57:52.471715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket&sid=sLY-oQMlHNsorbKEAAAh" host=complice.co request_id=8c937877-e06f-4503-b8af-a83a070d6aa0 fwd="184.175.46.182" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2125530ms status=101 bytes=504
2015-05-26T20:58:00.584527+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket&sid=pBl47HfKOimvv1V6AAAK" host=complice.co request_id=753f792d-e713-4086-901b-23727ee84a5e fwd="184.175.46.182" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2136303ms status=101 bytes=636
2015-05-26T20:58:05.233626+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket&sid=RekQs6Jh__ASc7GXAAAT" host=complice.co request_id=17c7ff23-d37f-4fdd-b944-9691c3d717f0 fwd="184.175.46.182" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=2140156ms status=101 bytes=577
2015-05-26T20:57:49.144350+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket&sid=P9rDPW9bvnvd18knAAA1" host=complice.co request_id=7157af69-a10a-45a1-859d-8e122256a1f8 fwd="184.175.46.182" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2120661ms status=101 bytes=498
2015-05-26T20:58:05.911121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket&sid=eUp5HE_WfsRMwEO6AAAp" host=complice.co request_id=1bc08b67-9574-4c3b-a69f-1e2272953c82 fwd="184.175.46.182" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2138245ms status=101 bytes=640
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest and easiest would be: 
`heroku logs -t | grep -v socket.io`.

You could do something more interesting with a logging library or service but with default heroku logging, you are sort of restricted because those are actual GET requests. I mean that you cannot suppress these with application code. As far as I am aware, you can only filter by source or process with heroku's default logging.

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to use `grep -v` that doesn't destroy the nice coloring the logs otherwise have?

Comment: The winning command: `unbuffer heroku logs -t | grep -v socket.io`